# array not iterating through each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Below is the **response** from the backend :

```js
results = [{
    "name": "FantasticBeasts",
    "count": 546809,
  },

  {
    "name": "SSIPOS",
    "count": 16257,
  },

  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "count": 16257,
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++) {
  console.log('result ==>', results[i]);
}
```

My end goal is to fetch the name from every element of the array. But before that, I need to iterate over the array elements. But I am unable to iterate through the array elements.

> result ==> undefined

Comment: Condition should be `i < results.length;` as index starts from `0`

Comment: The error is like @Satpal says: You might do this error again in the future, but someday the syntax of iterating over an array is that common to your mind that it is ideomatic and you will do it automatically in the correct way

Answer (score 4):

It should be `i < results.length` because with a `<=` you're comparing an additional non existing value.

```js
results = [{
    "name": "FantasticBeasts",
    "count": 546809,
  },

  {
    "name": "SSIPOS",
    "count": 16257,
  },

  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "count": 16257,
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  console.log('result ==>', results[i]);
}
```

Comment: the output is displaying with every character in the result for example:
result ==> {
result ==> "
result ==> n
.....

Comment: @Aditya and what output do you actually expect? This is how the console prints the results.

Comment: @Aditya this answer solves the problem (I have also upvoted it), but using a `forEach` is more advisable as discussed in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In javascript arrays are 0 indexed so, there are 0 to length-1 indexes.
So we need to run loop accordingly from 0 to `< length` or `<= length-1`

```js
results = [{
    "name": "FantasticBeasts",
    "count": 546809,
  },

  {
    "name": "SSIPOS",
    "count": 16257,
  },

  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "count": 16257,
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  console.log("Name:", results[i].name, "Count:", results[i].count);
}

results.forEach(function(result) {
  console.log("Name:", result.name, "Count:", result.count);
});
```

`forEach` is bit more cleaner way to achieve the same result.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2):

You iterate from `0` to `array.length-1`. So you have to replace:

```
i <= results.length;
```

by:

```
i < results.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `forEach` is more efficient in this case, as it's more testable and gives you more control without having to manually access the index.

`` results.forEach(r => console.log(`result ==> ${r.name}`)); ``

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at `.forEach` and then passing by reference the function (no parameters).

```
results.forEach(console.log);
```

This will console log each Result.